# How to show day and week number in JS?

Tags: javascript, date

I need to show day and week number + month for 7 days (5 Friday, June ... 6 Saturday, June etc.), I did something like that:

```
const getCurrentDate = (d) => {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]; 
    let day = days[d.getDay()];
    let date = d.getDate();
    let month = months[d.getMonth()];

    return `${day}, ${date} ${month}`
}
```

But it show only current day, week and month.

Of course everyday It has to update.

Comment: value - forgot to delete, d - without this param getDa , getDate, getMonth - not defined

Comment: So you're pushing today's date as the date object via the `d` parameter or some other date?

Comment: @AndrewL64 yes.

Comment: Is your question to show a list contains 7 date? Then use the for loop

Comment: ok, how to do this?))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a `for loop` and use the loop index to generate 7 dates from today by adding days to the current date on every loop using the [setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) method.

Also, you don't need to create arrays for the months and weekdays. Just use the [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) method to get the weekday and month from the date.

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
const today = new Date();
const showDate = document.querySelector("#showDate");

const getCurrentDate = (d) => {
    
    for(let i=0; i<7; i++){
     let x = new Date(d);
     x.setDate(x.getDate() + i);
      let day = x.toLocaleString('default', { weekday: 'long' });
      let date = x.getDate();
      let month = x.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
      
      showDate.innerHTML += `${day}, ${date} ${month} <br/>`;
    }   
}

getCurrentDate(today);
```

```html
<h1>Dates below:</h1>
<h2 id="showDate"></h2>
```

Or as @RobG mentioned in the comments, you can use `toLocaleString` to generate the weekday, date and month in one line like this:

```js
const today = new Date();
const showDate = document.querySelector("#showDate");

const getCurrentDate = (d) => {
    
    for(let i=0; i<7; i++){
     let x = new Date(d);
     x.setDate(x.getDate() + i);
      
      let fullDate = x.toLocaleString('en-gb', { weekday: 'long', day:'numeric', month: 'long' });
      
      showDate.innerHTML += `${fullDate}<br/>`;
    }   
}

getCurrentDate(today);
```

```html
<h1>Dates below:</h1>
<h2 id="showDate"></h2>
```

Comment: When I try to show it on the page, it shows only current day...

Comment: But in console there're all days)

Comment: hmm. Wait let me try to generate on HTML too in the above snippet.

Comment: I tried outputting the dates to HTML and it seems to work fine in the above snippet.

Comment: Thank you, my bad)